# Как запретить скроллинг контента под модальным окном?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Необходимо, чтобы контент под модальным окном не прокручивался. Само модальное окно может прокручиваться, если оно слишком длинное *(этот функционал уже реализован, просто предупреждаю, потому что видел решения, когда скроллинг блокировали вообще весь)*.

Я пробовал вариант с установкой `overflow: hidden`. В принципе он почти идеален, но не очень красиво выглядит из-за изменения ширины окна. То есть лучше бы полоса прокрутки оставалась.

Ещё я попробовал вот такой жёсткий вариант:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

Но он отбрасывает к началу страницу, это выглядит ещё хуже.

Каким образом я могу блокировать скроллинг, чтобы это:

1. Не убирало полосу прокрутки.
2. Не отбрасывало к верху страницы / не меняло бы положение на странице.

Comment: Используйте свой "жёсткий вариант", раз он работает совместно с модалкой. Только перед появлением модального окна, вычислите значение прокрутки и подставляйте его вместо ноля.

Comment: @UModeL хм, я думал над этим, но хотел избежать) Попробую

Comment: другой способ - используя `overflow: hidden`, добавлять паддинг на ширину полосы прокрутки. Естественно, что нужно её сначала вычислить.

Comment: @UModeL не, лучше уж "жесткий" вариант. Над такой штукой тоже думал, но не на всех страницах скролл есть - придётся и его вычислять, есть он или нет. Ну и паддинг будет не так органично смотреться, нежели скролл

Comment: Попробуйте еще `e.preventDefault()` в событии `scroll`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как модальные окна открываются/закрываются через скрипты, то не вижу препятствий для добавления в соответствующие обработчики пары-тройки строк вычисляющих наличие и ширину полосы прокрутки, с последующей её заменой на необходимый `padding-right`:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.style.paddingRight = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.scroll-fix')).width;
  document.body.classList.add('modal-show');
});
document.querySelector('div.modal-layer').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (this !== ev.target) return;
  document.body.classList.remove('modal-show');
  document.body.style.paddingRight = '0px';
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png'), radial-gradient(#fff8, #000f); background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: auto; display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; }

/* Обязательные правила */
body.modal-show { overflow: hidden; }

.scroll-fix {
  position: absolute;
  /* Вся магия в этой строчке ;-) */
  width: calc(100vw - 100%);
}

.modal-layer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: #8888;
}
.modal-show .modal-layer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Оформление для примера */
h1, button { margin: 25vh auto; display: flex; }
.modal-layer .modal-content { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 150px; width: 400px; padding: 1em; box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 0.5em; background-color: #fff; box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -0px #0008; }
.modal-layer .modal-text { height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: auto; overscroll-behavior-y: contain; }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="scroll-fix"></div>
  <h1>NoScrollThenModal</h1>
  <button>Modal</button>
  <div class="modal-layer">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-text">
        Это<br>окно<br>можно<br>закрыть,<br>сделав<br>щелчок<br>мышью<br>за его<br>пределами.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Да, очень хорошо работает. Но, блин, дёргается модальное окно на милисекунду. Вероятно это потому что я использую React и оно там отрисовывается по несколько раз. А может у меня компьютер медленный. Ну да ладно.

Comment: @Zhenyria: рад был помочь. На будущее - указывайте всё, что может быть важным или полезным для отвечающих (например, про React. Можно даже в метках). Дело в том, что отвечающие затрачивают время, делая под одну задачу, а после оказывается, что нужно всё с нуля переделывать из-за одной неточности в вопросе. Чем больше подробностей - тем более узкие спецы набегут и дадут самый оптимальный ответ. Удачи!

Comment: Да нет, мне вашего решения вполне хватает) Реакт я целенаправленно не стал указывать, чтобы люди не пугались, а то мало ли)

Comment: @Zhenyria: было ещё свойство `overflow: overlay` - это, когда прокрутка поверх контента (как на мобилах). Хорошая штука, но вроде устарело оно на десктопах, да и поддержка изначально была слабая.